# Delphi TComboBox Cancel Selection

Tags: delphi, combobox, tcombobox

I've got delphi TComboBox control on my form. It has element button on each line which is when clicked shows a new form with information on the item. What I need to do is when clicked on the button it shouldn't change previously selected item. Now I just restore the selected item which is not a good solution.
Do I need to override any events?

Thanks

Comment: Using a TComboBox to show another form doesn't sound like good interface design, in my humble opinion. If you're using the OnChange event, you will also see it gets fired when you (re)set the ItemIndex property to the previous value (or -1).

Comment: @Stijn - From the description it sounds like the combo box has something akin to an "info" icon next to each item, so that the user can "find out more" about the item without actually selecting it.  That's not necessarily a bad idea and isn't quite the same as "using a combo to show another form" in the way that I think you may be thinking, more like a detailed hint window.